# У микротика маршрут, используя mangle зависает

Tags: route, mikrotik

Работающий вариант такой :

```
/ip firewall nat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="ssh to server2" dst-port=31103 \
  in-interface=bridge1WAN protocol=tcp to-addresses=192.168.0.71
```

добавил впереди для пробы с mangle и метками :

```
/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-connection chain=prerouting comment=srvsshtcp \
  dst-address=195.18.xx.xx dst-port=31103 in-interface=bridge1WAN \
  new-connection-mark=srvsshtcp passthrough=yes protocol=tcp
add action=mark-packet chain=prerouting comment=srvsshtcpp connection-mark=srvsshtcp \
  new-packet-mark=srvsshtcpp passthrough=yes
/ip firewall nat
add action=dst-nat chain=dstnat comment="srvsshtcpp 192.168.0.71" \
  packet-mark=srvsshtcpp to-addresses=192.168.0.71
```

но этот вариант медленно работает с зависаниями.
Статистика говорит, что присваивание меток `srvsshtcp` и `srvsshtcpp` даёт статистику 10000 и 22000.
А dstnat выполнилось 1 раз.

Как правильно использовать mangle? Он мне нужен в дальнейшем для правильной обработки запросов также из внутренней сети.

Comment: Routeros v6+ ? На v5 не получится совсем

Comment: @eri `MikroTik RouterOS 6.49.8`

Answer (score 0):

dstnat работает один раз из-за conntrack. То что уже отмечено в коннектах как заNATченное в цепочку dst-nat не попадает.

Comment: я добавил `mangle` для дальнейшего удобства, а из-за этого удобства почему-то простая связь зависает. вопрос был связан с тем, что я не знаю причину этого обрыва связи. и выложил две версии настроек. почему работает первая версия, а вторая - нет?